# How to delete the last occurence of the match?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have the lyrics in the format like:

```
[00:26.8]Lo [00:27.0]rem[00:27.2] Ipsum[00:27.4] sam[00:27.6]ple [00:27.9]text[00:28.1] to [00:28.5]
[00:28.51]demonstrate[00:28.7] the[00:28.9] lyrics[00:29.1] text
```

I use the following regex to match time tags (`[hh:mm.ss]`):

```
/\[\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\.\d{0,2}\]/ig
```

But how can I find and delete the last time tag (`[00:29.1]` in the example above)? Understand that I can match all occurences, take the last one, find the position of according tag within the text (with `lastIndexOf` usage), then delete the tag. But is there any better way to achieve it?

Upd. There is one more condition - if the time tag is at the beginning of the line, then it shouldn't be removed. I.e. in case of the lyrics:

```
[00:26.8]Lo [00:27.0]rem[00:27.2] Ipsum[00:27.4] sam[00:27.6]ple [00:27.9]text[00:28.1] to [00:28.5]
[00:28.51]demonstrate
```

The tag found and deleted should be `[00:28.5]`, not `[00:28.51]`.

Comment: Does that input lyrics a single line string or multi line string?

Comment: @nu11p01n73R, multiline string (`\n` is used as the line separator).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also can do this without lookahead by adding a greedy `[^]*` or `[\s\S]*` before to eat up.

```
var str = str.replace(/^([^]*)(\[\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\.\d{0,2}\])/, "$1");
```

Replace with captured first part. [See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hw1qbf2v/)

---

Ad update: add a `[^\n]` before:

```
var str = str.replace(/^([\s\S]*[^\n])(\[\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\.\d{0,2}\])/, "$1");
```

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ymo6z9Lo/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Add a look ahead assertion to ensure that not `[..]` follows the matched string as

```
/\[\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\.\d{0,2}\](?!(.|\n)*\[)/
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/gT1hI9/1)

Comment: I think there is a missing closing paren before the closing slash

Comment: Many thanks. Could you please clarify how it works? And, I forgot to mention one more requirement - if the tag is in the beginning of the line, then it shouldn't be touched (will update the question in a few minutes).

Comment: it's not checking for a last time tag, just for an opening `[`

Comment: @LA_ The negative look ahead ensures that the matched string is not followed by another opening `[` (which in turn signifies another time tag)

Answer (score 0):

The following should do (It makes sure the wanted `[hh:mm.ss]` isnt followed by any other opening or closing bracket till the end of the string... wich means that it's the last one you're looking for):

```
(\[\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\.\d{0,2}\])(?=[^\]\[]*$)
```

[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/iO2iQ7/1)

Comment: Oh, the page showed me @nu11p01n73R's answer only after I posted mine... weird... I'll leave it anyway x_x